# ValueError: cannot handle a non-unique multi-index!

Tags: python, pandas

Пытаюсь объединить несколько DataFrame следующем путем, df получаю из `csv` файлов

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('/Users/04.csv', sep='\t')
df1

# col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 
# er    tr    rt  ty  rf
# df   gh   yh  ju    jk


df2 = pd.read_csv('/Users/05.csv', sep='\t')
df2


# col1 col2 col3 col4 col5
# rf   gb    th  yn   lk
# lk   pl   vb   sd   gb

load_df = [df1, df2]
index_columns = ['col1', 'col2']
res = pd.concat([df.set_index(index_columns) for df in load_df], axis=1)
print(res)
```

на выходе получаю ошибку:

```
ValueError: cannot handle a non-unique multi-index!
```

Просьба, подсказать, в связи с чем данная ошибка и как обойти,

Comment: а так работает: `res = df1.merge(df2, on=index_columns)` ?

Comment: @MaxU, нет, подобная ошибка

ValueError: You are trying to merge on object and int64 columns. If you wish to proceed you should use pd.concat

Comment: похоже здесь не обойтись без [mcve]-ов  данных в вопросе )

Comment: Похоже, что сочетание столбцов `['col1', 'col2']` содержит не уникальные значения и поэтому не может быть установлено в качестве индекса. И вообще покажите ваши данные и `.info()` датафреймов, похоже там как-то странно загрузилось всё.

Comment: для справки: "воспроизводимыми" - называются те примеры, которые позволяют __воспроизвести проблему__ ;)

Comment: @CrazyElf, блвгодарю за подсказку, к сожалению, да, набранный набор столбцов не содержал уникальные значения, добавил недостающие выполнилось без ошибок

Comment: Раз помогло, оформлю ответом.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Судя по ошибке, похоже, что сочетание столбцов `['col1', 'col2']` содержит не уникальные (повторяющиеся) значения и поэтому не может быть установлено в качестве индекса. Поменяйте данные или добавьте ещё какие-то столбцы в индекс, которые позволят ему стать уникальным.